# Каким образом Android-приложения могут использовать локальную базу данных SQLite без её прямой установки на ОС?

Tags: android

Во времена, когда я изучал программирование под Andorid я обратил внимание на то, что работа с локальной базой SQLite данных в Andorid SDK упрощена до предела: эффект был такой, как будто мы просто читали данные из внешнего XML-подобного файла, то есть не устанавливали никаких баз данных ни на компьютер ни на смартфон, не указывали никаких localhost-ов и портов, не указывали никаких логинов и паролей - всё просто работало из коробки. Теперь мне бы хотелось, чтобы эта магия была доступна и в моих JavaFX-приложениях, но ввиду того, что на данный момент моя профессия - фронтенд веб-разработчик, в базах данных я разбираюсь пока очень слабо и реализацию этой магии в один вопрос не уместить.

Первый мой вопрос в этих изысканиях будет о том, каким образом собранные Android-приложения могут использовать SQLite. Мы же ведь не устанавливали её на смартфон! С точки зрения логики это отнюдь неочевидно, и у меня как минимум две версии:

1. SQLite встроена в собранное приложение
2. SQLite предустановлена на OS Android

Если я создам приложение на JavaFX, использующее SQLite, а потом соберу его и попытаюсь запустить на другом компьютере, то скорее всего это закончится тем, что приложение работать не будет - базы данных-то нет. Почему же такой проблемы не возникает при разработке на Android и всё работает как часы, как будто мы просто читаем файл?

На всякий случай подчеркну, что данный вопрос не имеет никакого отношения к удалённым базам данных, к которым нужно реально подключаться через интернет. Речь идёт о **локальном хранении и чтении данных** в виде таблиц SQLite.

Comment: Драйвер sqlite может быть встроен в приложение (как и любые другие библиотеки, тем более sqlite очень простой). А файл базы sqlite, думаю, не сложно создать драйверу при первом запуске приложения (это делается в коде -- создание подключения + выполнение запросов, что создадут таблицы). Плюс, приложения ведь имеют доступ к файловой системе телефона, поэтому создавать файлы тоже могут (только не знаю это специальные папки для конкретных приложений или общая папка, а в ней из кода приложения создается папка для него же)

Comment: сама sqlite и классы для работы с ней являются частью фреймворка Android

Comment: @gil9red, благодарю Вас за комментарий! Из Вашего ответа я узнал узнал о существовании нового смысла слова "драйвер" - я думал, что "драйвер" - это ПО с помощью которого другое программное обеспечение получает доступ к аппаратному обеспечению некоторого устройства. Но SQLite - это не аппаратное обеспечение. Нужно будет пособирать информацию по этому поводу...

Comment: @pavlofff, благодарю Вас за комментарий! Подскажите пожалуйста, я правильно понял, что во фреймворке прописаны все хосты, порты и прочая информация, необходимая для получению доступа к базе данных.

Comment: @БоковГлеб, драйвер это общее понятие и не только относящиеся к железу, погуглите ODBC. sqlite не работает с портами и хостами, это локальная база и работа у нее через файл (хотя можно и в памяти держать базу данных в соединении sqlite вместо названия файла указать строку `:memory:`)

Comment: @gil9red, хорошо, спасибо ещё раз. Буду дальше искать информацию в этом направлении.

Comment: @БоковГлеб, пожалуйста :) Как найдете ответ на свой вопрос, добавьте его как ответ ;)